# How to show that the bipolar co-ordinates are othogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, orthogonality, spherical-coordinates

> How to show that the bipolar co-ordinates are othogonal
>
> where $x=\dfrac{\sin hv}{\cos hv-\cos u},y=\dfrac{\sin u}{\cos hv-\cos u},z=z$
>
> where $u\in [0,2\pi]$ and $y,z\in (-\infty,\infty)$.

How to show a system is orthogonal?

Do I need to compute the angle between them?If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Given $x(u,v), y(u,v)$ find

$t_x = (x_u,x_v), \, t_y = (y_u, y_v)$

and then verify that

$t_x\cdot t_y = 0$

Comment: what is $t_x,t_y$,i dont get that

Comment: $t_x =\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\right)$ etc.